# SQL insert into - for loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into, logfile

How do I make SQL Server commit inserts in chunks? I need to copy a large amount of rows from an old db into a new table, and it has several problems:

1. it takes ages to finish, and I don't see any rows in my table until the entire transaction is finished.
2. my log file is growing like crazy and it will probably run out of space.
3. if something breaks in the middle, I have to repeat everything.

If I add `SET ROWCOUNT 500`, I can limit the number of rows, but I don't know how to continue with the last inserted ID. I might query the new table to see what got inserted last, but I am not sure if that's the right thing to do. And it's a bit difficult because my `where` clause does not use the `ID` column, so I am not sure how to know exactly where to continue.

What's the best approach for this? Is there a "for loop" or something which would allow me to commit every once in a while?

I am using SSMS for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: what about [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.105).aspx) ?

Comment: @danihp: is it possible to filter that? I mean, to add a `where` clause? It only seems to copy entire tables.

Comment: Perhaps this can helps you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422(v=sql.105).aspx . Also `BATCHSIZE =batch_size` is not enough for you (instead where clause) ?

Comment: @danihp: the problem is, I only want to import data for a specified time period (so I need to query on a specific column).

Comment: bulk insert imports data from a datafile. You should create your datafile only with rows should be imported. Or you can import to a temporary table and them merge your data to the final table as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if TomTom's answer is sarcastic, it contains two basic options, which may help you:

1. You can write a loop in T-SQL (see for example [while](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178642%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)) and use TOP and OFFSET to select chunks (you need an order by). You can minimize looging according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). And if you just worry about restarting without redoing everything this should be fine, though I don't expect it to be fast.
2. You can export your selection to a file and use the bulk insert to load it.

Some more options you may find [here (About Bulk Import and Bulk Export Operations)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [here (INSERT Section Best Practices)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174335.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, although I ended up writing a small console app to transfer the data in chunks in the end.

Answer (score -5):

> How do I make SQL Server commit inserts in chunks?

You program code that inserts it in chunks, quite easy.

1: Yes, that is how transactions work, you know.

2: Yes, that is how transactions work, you know.

3: Yes, guess what - THAT IS HOW TRANSACTIONS WORK, you know ;)

> but I don't know how to continue with the last inserted ID

Called programming. Generate ID's on client side. Remember the last one you generated.

In general, I would advice not to INSERT in code - depending how your code works, this sounds like a data copy operation, and there are other mechanisms for that (bulk copy interface).

> I am using SSMS for SQL Server 2008 R2

Basically it behaves as you program it. You can easily put in some loop in the SSMS side, or export to a file, then bulk insert the file. Wont help you with item 2 though... unless you go to simple backup model and do not care about restoring.

Also 3 is complex then - how do you properly restart? Lots of additional code.

The best approach depends on the circumstances, and sadly you are way too vague to make more than a blind guess.

Comment: A 1000 internets to your sir, that's a concise and helpful answer.

Comment: Hey, seems like you're a bit excited lately.  Maybe you need to take a little mini vacation.  You know, relax and take it easy.